# Pandas unix time stamp to microseconds

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

whats the approach to converting a unix time stamp which is in microseconds to datetime?

for example: `1632527998056329`

`pd.to_datetime(data['local_timestamp'],unit='ms')`

doesn't seem to work. I have a column with unix timestamp with microsecond granularity which I need to convert and set as index.

The above code returns an error:
`pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input with unit 'ms'`

The above code works when the unix time stamp is for milliseconds. I don't think there is one for microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

In Pandas, it's actually named `us`. Not `ms` since that represents milliseconds.

So microseconds also starts with `m`, but it's named `us`:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(1632527998056329, unit='us')
Timestamp('2021-09-24 23:59:58.056329')
>>>
```

---

So in your case do:

```
data['local_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['local_timestamp'], unit='us')
```